# std exceptions inviting unsafe usage?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor, std

It is recommended that you always throw something derived from `std::exception` and there are a few predefines specialisations such as `std::runtime_error`

`std::exception`'s interface is given in terms of non-throwing accessors. Great. Now look at the constructor for `std::runtime_error`

```
class runtime_error : public exception {
public:
  explicit runtime_error (const string &);
};
```

So if I do *this*

```
try {
    foo ();
}
catch (...) {
    throw std :: runtime_error ("bang");
}
```

it's entirely possible that `foo` threw because it's out of memory, in which case constructing the `string` argument to `runtime_error` can also throw. This would be a throw-expression which itself also throws: won't this will call `std::terminate`?

Doesn't this mean we should always do this instead:

```
namespace {
    const std :: string BANG ("bang");
}

...

try {
    foo ();
}
catch (...) {
    throw std :: runtime_error (BANG);
}
```

BUT WAIT this won't work either, will it? Because `runtime_error` is going to copy its argument, which may also throw...

...so doesn't this mean that there is no safe way to use the standard specialisations of `std::exception`, and that you should always roll your own string class whose constructor only fails without throwing?

Or is there some trick I'm missing?

Comment: Use a standard library implementation with small string optimization (no allocation) and very short error messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your main problem is that you are doing `catch(...)` and translating to a `std::runtime_error` thereby losing all type information from the original exception. You should just rethrow with `throw()`.

Practically, if you are short of memory you are likely have a `bad_alloc` exception thrown at some point and there's not a lot else you can - or should - do. If you *want* to throw an exception for a reason other than an allocation failed then you are not likely to have a problem constructing a sensible exception object with meaningful contextual information. If you hit a memory issue while formatting your exception object there's not a lot you can do other than propagate the memory error.

You are right that there is a potential problem if you construct a new string object to construct an exception, but if you want to format a message with context this can't be avoided in general. Note that the standard exception objects all have a `const char*` constructor (as of last week) so if you have a `const char*` that you want to use you don't have to construct a new `std::string` object.

`std::runtime_error` must copy it's argument, but not necessarily as a new string object. There could be an area of statically allocated memory which it can the contents of its argument to. It only has to fulfil the `what()` requirements which only requires returning a `const char *`, it doesn't have to store a `std::string` object.

Comment: Well - you can free memory in some cases and hope it is not fragmented. It might be also pointed out that some systems may overcommit memory so the exception will be thrown when the process run out of virtual memory (in case of 64-bit systems it means never even with "only" 48-bit address space, in case of 32-bit it usually is 3GiB assuming 1GiB of high memory).

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka: In the case of a system that overcommits, it's very unlikely that a C++ exception will be thrown - at least not in any conforming way - because the memory 'error' will only be detected at a point where it is not permissible to throw an exception.

Comment: Ups. Sorry - there is missing 'only'. IIRC every system will throw exception when the virtual memory is exhausted and overcommiting will throw usually only then (it might kill the process though). My comment seems to imply that the exception on vm exhaustion will be thrown only in overcommiting OS which, of course, make no sense.

Answer (score 3):

> This would be a throw-expression which itself also throws: won't this
>   will call std::terminate?

No, it wouldn't. It would just throw the exception about insufficient memory. The control will not reach the outer `throw` part.

> BUT WAIT this won't work either, will it? Because runtime_error is
>   going to copy its argument, which may also throw...

Exception classes with a throwing copy-constructors are as evil as throwing destructors. Nothing that can really be done about it.

Answer (score 3):

`std::runtime_error` is designed to treat the usual runtime errors, not
out of memory or other such critical exceptions.  The base class
`std::exception` does **not** do anything which may throw; nor does
`std::bad_alloc`.  And obviously, remapping `std::bad_alloc` into an
exception which requires dynamic allocation to work is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is what would you want to do if you happen to have a **bad_alloc** exception because you're out of memory?

I'd say in a classic C++ program, you'd want to have the program somehow trying to tell you what happened and then terminates.

In a classic C++ program you'd then let the **bad_alloc** exception propagate to the main section of the program. The main will contain an arragement of try/catch like this:

```
int main()
{
   try
   {
      // your program starts
   }
   catch( const std::exception & e )
   {
       std::cerr << "huho something happened" << e.what() << std::endl;
   }
   catch( ... )
   {
       std::cerr << "huho..err..what?" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

you'll only use **catch( ... )** inside the main and at the starting functions of threads. Contrary to some other languages like Java you're not expected to catch all possible exceptions locally. You just let them propagate until you catch them where you wanted to.

Now if you have code that specifically must check **std::bad_alloc**, you should only **catch( const std::bad_alloc & )** locally. And there it should maybe wise to do something else rather than just rethrow another exception.

I found in The C++ Programming Language §14.10 also that the C++ exception-handling mechanism keeps a bit of memory to itself for holding exceptions, so that throwing a standard library exception will not throw an exception by itself. Of course it is possible also to let the exception-handling mechanism run out of memory if you really code something perverted.

So, to sum up, if you do nothing and let big exceptions like **bad_alloc** propagate nicely where you want to catch them, in my opinion you're safe. And you should not use **catch( ... )** or **catch(const std::exception & )** anywhere except in the main function and in the starting functions of threads.

Catching all exceptions to rethrow a single exception is really the last thing to do. You lose every advantages you got with the C++ exception-handling mechanism.